# Find$\lim\limits_{x\to 0+} x\ln(\sin(x)) =??$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

I'm wondering how to solve the limit $$\lim\limits_{x\to 0+} x\ln(\sin(x))$$ using the standard limit $$\lim\limits_{x\to 0+} x\ln(x) $$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please always put your question within the body of the question.

Answer (score 4):

Consider the trickery:

$x\log (x(\dfrac{\sin x}{x}) ) =$

$x (\log(x) + \log(\dfrac {\sin x}{x})).$

Helps?

Answer (score 2):

By pulling $x/\sin x$ out and by the change of variable $y:=\sin x$,

$$\lim\limits_{x\to 0+} x\ln(\sin(x))=\lim\limits_{x\to 0+} \frac x{\sin(x)}\lim\limits_{x\to 0+}\sin x\ln(\sin(x))=\lim\limits_{y\to 0+}y\ln(y).$$

Answer (score 0):

Since, $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow0^+}x^x=1$, we obtain:
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0^+}x\ln{\sin{x}}=\lim_{x\rightarrow0^+}\left(\frac{x}{\sin{x}}\cdot\ln(\sin{x})^{\sin{x}}\right)=1\cdot0=0.$$

Comment: can you tell me can i do it this way?
we have $\ln y < y$ 
So $x \ln \sin x < x (\sin x) < x.x \to 0$ and so given limit tends to zero.

My doubt is can i freely use these inequalities:-log x < x; sin x < x; sometimes i have seen sinx < 1

Comment: If i take $f(x) = \ln x - x, f'(x) = (1/x) - 1 < 0$ means x > 1. But here as we are checking limit in neighborhood of 0, i can'nt use this inequality right????

Comment: @anirudh b  I used $x\ln\sin{x}=\frac{x}{\sin{x}}\cdot\ln(\sin{x})^{\sin{x}}$. See please my solution.

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim\limits_{x\to 0+} x\ln(\sin(x))=\lim\limits_{x\to 0+}\frac{x}{\sin x}\sin x\ln(\sin(x)) \\= \lim\limits_{x\to 0+}\frac{x}{\sin x}\lim\limits_{x\to 0+}\sin x\ln(\sin(x))  \\=\lim\limits_{x\to 0+}\frac{x}{\sin x}\lim\limits_{h\to 0+}h\ln(h) =0 $$
With $h =\sin x$

Given that, $$\lim\limits_{x\to 0+}\frac{\sin x}x=1$$
and $$\lim\limits_{h\to 0+} h\ln(h) = 0$$